# xpath query url with one folder depth only

Tags: xpath

I am using this XPath query succesfully:

```
//div[(@class="result")]//a[contains(@href,"pinterest.com")]/@href
```

The URL I am using the XPath query (with simple_html_dom.php) is **[this](https://www.startpage.com/do/asearch?cmd=process_search&query=host%3Apinterest.com%20warner%20bros)** one here.
Now, I would like to find results for **`pinterest.com/one-folder-deep-only`** and exclude all URLs deeper than one directory, like **`pinterest.com/one-folder-deep-only/this`** or **`pinterest.com/one-folder-deep-only/this/this`**. I have no idea if there is a way to achieve that. Have googled a lot, but not found anything. Maybe my search terms weren't the best.

Do you have any ideas? Thanks for helping me here.

I am testing the query using the **[Chrome XPath Helper](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/xpath-helper/hgimnogjllphhhkhlmebbmlgjoejdpjl)**.

Answer (score 0):

"//" is to evaluate all levels/depths. Instead use only one "/" for the "a" query  to only evaluate immediate children

```
//div[(@id="first-result")]/a[contains(@href,"url.com")]/@href
```

Note use of / instead of // before the "a" tag.

Comment: Can't get this to work. No results are found using this version. But thanks anyway.

Answer (score 0):

Try below XPath to select `@href` from required anchors only:

```
//a[contains(@href, "url.com") and not(contains(substring-after(./@href, 'url.com/'), "/"))]/@href
```

Solution for XPath 2.0:

```
//a[contains(@href, "url.com") and count(tokenize(@href, "/"))=2]/@href
```

Note that if in real HTML source `href` starts-with `"http://url.com"` you should specify `=4` instead of `=2`

Comment: I have tried the first line, but I can't get any results :(

Comment: Can you provide HTML code sample for the same? Also specify the tool you use

Comment: I have edited my question above with some more information and the URL I am using the query on. Thanks for your help and time!

Comment: Oh, I see... That's because actually reference looks like `pinterest.com/one-folder-deep-only/`, but not `pinterest.com/one-folder-deep-only`. I'll try to find another solution

Comment: Try this one `//a[contains(@href, "www.pinterest.com") and not(matches(@href, "https://www.pinterest.com/\w+/\w+"))]/@href`

Comment: Trying this with the XPath Helper plugin for Chrome results in "[INVALID XPATH EXPRESSION]". Could you make it work?

Comment: Did you try it in your real code? In my XPath checker I got 'https://www.pinterest.com/warnerbrosent/'
'https://www.pinterest.com/wbpictures/'
'https://www.pinterest.com/warnerbrosuk/'